# My code not working . I tried to dynamically generate elements.How to do it?

Tags: javascript, jsp

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function formQuestion(button_id,question_no)
    {
        document.getElementById(button_id).addEventListener('change',function(){

        var div=document.createElement("div");
        document.body.appendChild(div);

        var textarea=document.createElement("textarea");
        textarea.setAttribute("cols","90px");
        textarea.setAttribute("rows","20px");
        textarea.setAttribute("style","border:solid 4px black; resize:none");
        textarea.setAttribute("id","tid");
        textarea.setAttribute("name","tid");

       //how to append textarea to div ?
        document.body.appendChild(textarea);

        var upload=document.createElement("input");
        upload.setAttribute("type","file");
        upload.setAttribute("onclick","upload(this.id,'tid')");
        document.body.appendChild(upload);

        var buttone=document.createElement("button");
        buttone.setAttribute("type","button");
        document.body.appendChild(buttone);

    }
})
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <br><br><br>
    <% for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
    {%>
    <button type="button" onclick="formQuestions(this.id,'<%= i+1%>')" id=<%= i+1+"button"%>>Question<%= i+1 %></button>
    <br><br><br>    
    <%}
    %>

    </body>
    </html>
```

What I want to do -
1.The 'question buttons' are generated according to loop.
2.Each 'question button' should create a div consisting text area,upload button and a normal button on click.
3. If I click on other question button let's say ' question 2' then the question button 1's div should hide itself but contents must be there.

Please Help! 
NOTE- number of questions= provided by user. Not Fixed. It varies.

Answer (score -1):

If the number of questions are fixed then why don't you just write it directly to the html and use the JS code to hide/show when you need 'em.

Comment: it's not fixed. it could vary. User provides it.